# gitlabci with docker executor fails but command inside docker container works

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a gitlabci file like below. For some reason the second stage tfsec is failing with the error "wget not found"

```
image: ubuntu:18.04

stages:
  - wget_install
  - tfsec

wget install:
  stage: 'wget_install'
  script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y wget

Terraform Security:
  stage: 'tfsec'
  script:
    - wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/1.0.9/terraform_1.0.9_linux_amd64.zip
    - unzip terraform_1.0.9_linux_amd64.zip
    - chmod 770 ./terraform
    - ./terraform init
    - tfsec='https://github.com/tfsec/tfsec/releases/download/v1.27.1/tfsec-linux-amd64'
    - wget $tfsec
    - chmod 777 tfsec-linux-amd64
    - pwd
    - ls
    - ./tfsec-linux-amd64 --format JUnit ./
```

Error in gitlab ci pipeline

```
$ wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/1.0.9/terraform_1.0.9_linux_amd64.zip
/bin/bash: line 124: wget: command not found 
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables     00:00  
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

If I try the same script for installing wget inside a docker image it works.

```
docker run --rm -it ubuntu:18.04 bash 
root@693265d936eb:/# apt-get install -y wget 
root@693265d936eb:/# wget wget: missing URL Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...
Try `wget --help' for more options.
```

What am I missing in the gitlabci file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are installing wget in one job and then trying to use it in another. Each job runs in a separate container.
Try moving the wget installation to the same job. In this example I have used the `before_script` key:

```
image: ubuntu:18.04

stages:
  - tfsec

Terraform Security:
  stage: 'tfsec'
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y wget
  script:
    - wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/1.0.9/terraform_1.0.9_linux_amd64.zip
    - unzip terraform_1.0.9_linux_amd64.zip
    - chmod 770 ./terraform
    - ./terraform init
    - tfsec='https://github.com/tfsec/tfsec/releases/download/v1.27.1/tfsec-linux-amd64'
    - wget $tfsec
    - chmod 777 tfsec-linux-amd64
    - pwd
    - ls
    - ./tfsec-linux-amd64 --format JUnit ./
```

Comment: Thankyou  @Glen Thomas .. This helps :) .. Just one more query on this. If we want to use the same container in multiple stages, how to do that then? If we include this wget installation in same stage, then if I want to use the container with wget in another stage, how to do that?

Comment: You can't use the same container. You should instead create a custom image with wget installed, or find an existing one that meets your requirements.